# Tracking dependency loop in kernel/kconfig

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, make

I'd like to track a dependency loop in the linux kernel kconfig setup.

When compiling with gcc-6.3 I can do the following without no issues:

```
$ make ARCH=powerpc custom_defconfig
$ make ARCH=powerpc CROSS_COMPILE=powerpc-linux-gnu-
```

However now if I try again with a gcc-8.2 release, it seems something new get's triggered. And instead I get:

```
$ make ARCH=powerpc custom_defconfig
$ make ARCH=powerpc CROSS_COMPILE=powerpc-linux-gnu-
  GEN     Makefile
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
*
* Restart config...
*
*
* General architecture-dependent options
*
OProfile system profiling (OPROFILE) [M/n/y/?] m
Kprobes (KPROBES) [Y/n/?] y
Optimize very unlikely/likely branches (JUMP_LABEL) [N/y/?] n
Stack Protector buffer overflow detection (STACKPROTECTOR) [Y/n/?] (NEW)
```

I have of course verified my `custom_defconfig` is minimal (no diff against a `savedefconfig` run). So it seems I am triggering some kind of loop in the kconfig option. How do I track them, in order to report something accurate back to the kernel maintainers ?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was not dependency loop whatsoever, it was just a user error, the correct steps are to use the same compiler in the configuration and the build, eg:

```
$ make ARCH=powerpc CROSS_COMPILE=powerpc-linux-gnu- custom_defconfig
$ make ARCH=powerpc CROSS_COMPILE=powerpc-linux-gnu-
```